# Use PKCS#8 encoded rsa key with flutter or android

Tags: android, flutter, encryption, rsa

I am working with a server, and the server will give it's public key, but it is formatted with PKCS#8 (so RSA/ECB/OAEP with SHA-1 and MGF-1 Padding), everything I have found with both flutter use PKCS#1, with the standard padding.

The servers public key is also in a pem file, so there is no issues with getting the key and decrypting the key with base64, but I can't find a way to convert between the key types.

Also, any encrypted message would need to be sent with the OAEP padding, in order for the server to understand it.

As the encryption can't be changed on the server end, (due to other existing frontends), I was wondering if this is possible.

I have tried [*simple_rsa*](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_rsa)

And have looked at [*rsa_encrypt*](https://pub.dev/packages/rsa_encrypt)

But neither support OAEP padding.

For clarification, the public keys are generated by cryptopp with c++. It is then encoded to base64 and written to a pem file with correct headers. According to the docs, it uses `X509PublicKey` [docs](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#Public_Key_Format). I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Is there any way to do this through flutter or native code, as flutter can run native code, but flutter code would be ideal?

Comment: Public key in PKCS#8 format? PKCS#8 Padding? [PKCS#8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_8) is a format for private keys. The format for public keys would be X.509/SPKI. Both formats are not exclusive to RSA. In contrast, PKCS#1 specifies public key cryptography based on RSA, see [RFC8017](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017), e.g. padding (Chapter 7) and key formats (Chapter A.1).

Comment: @Topaco, thats my bad, the public key is gotten from cryptopp, and is formatted with X509, according to the docs, but still has different padding than PKCS#1, I have been checking paddings with [this](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption). Will edit to clarify